# Remove seconds from current date in Redshift (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

In Amazon Redshift I'm looking to convert the current timestamp to have 0 seconds.  That is go from this:

```
2013-12-17 12:27:50
```

to this:

```
2013-12-17 12:27:00
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT dateadd(second, -(date_part(second, getdate())), getdate());
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", double precision, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

SELECT dateadd(second, -cast(date_part(second, getdate()) as double precision), getdate());
ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", double precision, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

SELECT getdate() - date_part(second, getdate());
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - double precision
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm probably missing a very simple way of doing this!  Does anyone have any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easiest to use the [`date_trunc()` function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html), but that will work only while selecting:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', TIMESTAMP '2013-12-17 12:27:00');
```

You may preprocess data before loading data into the redshift DB, or use intermediary table and then use [`INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html):

```
INSERT INTO destination_table (
    SELECT date_trunc('minute', date_column), other_columns_here    
    FROM source_table
);
```

Comment: Incredible, thank you - somehow this function passed me by as I was perusing the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check [date_trunc()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute', TIMESTAMP '2013-12-17 12:27:00');
```

Answer (score -1):

You could format the date with:

```
select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:00');
```